# JSON data error, cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to get content from my API. The content is stored as HTML that needs to be displayed. How can I display the content without having one character per key:

```
const getContent = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await getItem(KEY);
        console.log(JSON.parse(response))
        return JSON.parse(response);
    } catch (e) {
        logger.error('Error getting content', e);
        throw e;
    }
};
```

Response:

> {66: "<", 67: "/", 68: "h", 69: "2", 70: ">", 71: "<", 72: "u", 73: "l", 74: ">", 75: "<", 76: "l", 77: "i", 78: ">", 79: "P", 80: "u", 81: "l", 82: "l", 83: " ", 84: "o", 85: "v", 86: "e", 87: "r", 88: " ", 89: "s", 90: "a", 91: "f", 92: "e", 93: "l", 94: "y", 95: "<", 96: "/", 97: "l", 98: "i", 99: ">", …}

My reducer then gives me this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'informationOverlay' of undefined:

```
case CONTENT_SUCCESS:
{
  return {
    ...state,
    informationOverlay: action.payload.informationOverlay,
    loading: false,
  };
}

const getItem = async (key) => {
    try {
        const result = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
        return result;
    } catch (e) {
        logger.error('getItem', e);
        throw e;
    }
};
```

Comment: What does the response from the API look like in the network inspector? What does `getItem` look like?

Comment: Then fix `getItem()`

Comment: You need to post the data we asked for or delete the question. It's already on the verge of being closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Object.values(JSON.parse(response)).join('')` but improving the response might be a better idea.

Comment: How does this answer the question?